# Parsear una fecha de LocalDateTime

Tags: java

Mi idea es convertir una fecha como esta: `12/30/12 18:20` refiriéndose a **año/día/mes hora:minuto** para añadirlo a mi clase. El problema es que hay fechas que vienen con un solo carácter y no sé como convertirlos, a un carácter me refiero que vienen así: `1/1/01 0:01`

El código que tengo ahora mismo es este:

```
LocalDateTime fechaCrimen = LocalDateTime.parse(sp[1].trim(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Y-d-M H:mm"));
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Deberías intentar modificando tu *Pattern* a `""yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm"` especificando que quieres dos dígitos

Comment: ¿Pero eso cómo lo especifico?

Comment: Los patrones están explicados en la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Para el caso que expones: `d`  serviría para el día del mes; `M` serviría para el mes, con y sin cero delante; `y` serviría para el año, con dos o con cuatro cifras; `H` para la hora en formato 24 horas (valores entre 0 y 23); y `m` para los minutos. En base a eso armarías el patrón. Tampoco queda claro en tu pregunta cuál es el valor para el año, ni qué resultados estás obteniendo  ¿?

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo un ejemplo de una **fecha de entrada** , que viene como String. Solo tienes que darle un formato con **formatter**, y parsearla. Indicando en que formato la quieres en este caso dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm , que se refiere a dia/mes/año hora/minutos

```
String fechaInput = "01/02/2020 09:57:02"; //fecha de entrada
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); // formato que quieras la fecha
LocalDateTime fechaOutput = LocalDateTime.parse(fechaInput, formatter); //parsea a LocalDateTime , la fecha de entrada con el respectivo formato indicado
```

Comment: @Alvaro si te ha servido no olvides marcar la respuesta como válida , un saludo